# JQuery and document ready firing repeatedly when loading data into a control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

For some reason, document ready and all associated functions fire multiple times (usually twice, but sometimes even endlessly) ever since I've added the load function to a control within document ready (meant to load content into a DIV when the current document is already loaded).

These are the scripts I'm using in my head tag and these are included in all pages (the page loaded into another, would have the same script, which is what I suspect causing the problem):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/mainscript.js"></script>
```

mainscript.js code:

```
var counter = 1;
var hasLoaded = false;
$(document).ready(function () {

if (!hasLoaded) {
    hasLoaded = true;
    if ($('.next-page').attr("data-loaded") == "false") {

        console.log(counter + ") STARTED LOADING!");
        $(this).attr("data-loaded", "true");
        $('.next-page').load($('.next-page').attr("data-link"), function () {
            counter++;
            $(this).attr("data-loaded", "true");
            console.log(counter + ") FINISHED LOADING!");
        });

    }
}

$('.tbDropDownBig li').click(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input').val($(this).text());
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(100);
});
```

});

OUTPUT from above console.log commands:

> 1) STARTED LOADING! 
>      2) FINISHED LOADING! 
>     1) STARTED LOADING! 
>      2) FINISHED LOADING! 
>      2) FINISHED LOADING!

**Direction to detecting the problem:**
The page loaded into "next-page" runs the same script, when loaded, of document load (because ALL pages have this script).

So it loads the data again. That is why I put the data-loaded attribute, but it hasn't helped.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem when I throw this code in a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fruz7/ . So I suspect the problem lies with something you've not posted. What, for example, is loaded by `$('.next-page').load(...)`? What is the basic page this javascript operates on? Things you can try is to remove as much from your page as you can to eliminate possible causes.

Comment: @towr Without the mentioned code everything works smoothly. I think the problem is caused because "next-page" always contains the same script, with the same document.load information.. 

My direction to finding the problem is - The loaded page calls the same thing and the "hasLoaded" variable does not apply to it, so it re-does the action of loading the data into "next-page". 

I will try to dig deeper, but I've been sitting on it for longer than it deserves.

Comment: Sounds like you have plenty postbacks.

Comment: @Pierre Yes, possibly. Note that all JQuery ready-related events also occur twice (if not more than twice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by stopping use of "ready", instead, binded "load" event to window like this:

```
function LoadNextPage() {
    if (!hasLoaded) {
        $('.next-page').load($('.next-page').attr("data-link"), function () {
            $(this).attr("data-loaded", "true");
            hasLoaded = true;
        });
    }
}

$(window).bind("load", function() {
    LoadNextPage();
});
```